# Using Angular Generate Component does not make the new component globally available

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-components

I'm trying to generate new components so that I can break down different parts of my project into components.

Using the CLI command ng g c components/test will generate the .html, .scss, .spec.ts, and .components.ts files but it will not update the app.module.ts, which I believe is used to make the component globally available in the project. When I try to do it myself, I instead get a black screen with a "shadow root" tag in chrome dev tools.

Currently, to make the association work I have copied the example from explore-container (template component generated with the project) and created .module.ts files for each component and then import/declare them where needed in the other pages or components. This doesn't seem intuitive or correct, so I wanted to ask if anyone has any advice. Thanks!

Note: This is an Ionic Angular project, not sure if that is relevant.

Tried using ng g c components/test. Got the files, but couldn't use the component globally.

Comment: `ng g c component` should automatically add an entry to the app.module.ts file. if it's not, then something is not set up correctly with your angular installation.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI imports the generated component/directive/pipe in the closest and most logical module for that class.

Generally, when the CLI is not able to follow the previous process, the action breaks and you should get an error similar to the following one:

```
Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.
```

You can avoid this error by using the skip-import flag.

So:

1. Make sure you are not using the skip-import flag when generating the component.
2. Check if the component is maybe imported in some other module
3. Try with the module flag to specify in which module you want to import the component: `ng g c (component Name) --project=(project Name*) --module=app`

Generally, when you are developing some shared components, it can make sense to have a specific module for each shared component and import this module when you want to use the shared component in some other component.